# Design for planar antenna that radiates in the plane of the antenna

Tags: antenna

Im trying to find a reference planar antenna design. The goal would be to design an antenna that radiates omnidirectionally on the pcb plane.

One solution would be to use an electrically small loop antenna. However, it might not radiate efficiently enough.

Can you recommend any other designs that would achieve a radiation pattern that is on the same plane as the planar antenna.

BR, Mikey

Comment: frequency and bandwidth, please.

Comment: for Zigbee applications so 2.44 GHz +/- 100 MHz

Comment: which software do you use? judging by my experience you can use CST Suite to create an antenna prototype and then use an optimizer to satisfy your criterion. HFSS can also be of help.

Answer (score 1):

At 2.44GHz, a patch antenna could suit your needs.

See for example this one:
http://esatjournals.net/ijret/2014v03/i05/IJRET20140305001.pdf

Or if the omnidirectionality spec. is not that strict, an inverted-F antenna is commonly used:
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra117d/swra117d.pdf

Edit: In case I misread, and you don't mean normal to the pcb plane:
Just run a dipole antenna along the edge of the PCB without any metal next to it ;)